# Проблема с работой input file на iPhone 6(iOS 12) - как решить?

Tags: javascript

При помощи JavaScript создаётся **input file**. Диалог выбора файла вызывается при помощи **click()**
На android и других iphone все нормально, а вот на **iPhone 6 - iOS 12** при выборе файла первый раз событие "change" не срабатывает, а второй раз и далее срабатывает. Как это можно решить? Может кто встречался с подобным?

```js
function func1(){
  var fInput = document.createElement('input');
  fInput.type = 'file';
  fInput.style.display = "none";
  fInput.accept = 'image/*';
  fInput.addEventListener('change',function(){
    console.log('Change file!');
    alert('Change file!');
  });
  document.body.appendChild(fInput);
  fInput.click();
}
```

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="func1();">
  Кликни
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `ontouchstart onclick`

Comment: @IgorR.проблема не в клике, а в событии change. Т.е. окно выбора файла на iOS открывается, а вот после выбора файла ничего не происходит, а второй раз выбирая файл срабатывает change как положено и загрузка файла происходит.